# How to view and edit large delimiter separated value files?

Tags: editing, table, large-files, csv

I have been using `csv-mode` to modify small to medium sized CSV files, but recently I have been working with large files containing more than 40,812 entries. `csv-mode` struggles to align and navigate the tables, and is too slow to be usable as is.  In comparison, LibreOffice Calc can zip through the file.

Is there a simple way to make `csv-mode` handle large tables, or is there a better approach available?

I am aware of [a related Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616525/is-there-a-good-emacs-mode-for-displaying-and-editing-huge-delimiter-separated-f). Its solution was to only align the portion of buffer in the visible window, but this did not solve the sluggishness in my case.

[Here is an example file.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xmt4s5i5ikq0i0v/big.csv?dl=0)  I tried to make it large, but not so large it will freeze Emacs on older computers.

Comment: Table editing is not one of Emacs's current strengths. I wish it was. I'd rather never have to use a dedicated spreadsheet.

Comment: Not a short-term answer, but you might want to `M-x report-emacs-bug` about it, ideally with a recipe to reproduce the slow-down.  There's probably a lot of room for improvement in `csv-mode`.

Comment: Do you have a sample file that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Yes, yes I do. Added to question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With `csv-mode` I can see some lags with your file, but only with syntax highlighting enabled. After disabling fontification with `M-x font-lock-mode` it works without problems.

To disable it permanently for `csv-mode` add to your config:

```
(add-hook 'csv-mode-hook (lambda () (font-lock-mode -1))
```

Or if you are a [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) user:

```
(use-package csv-mode
  :mode ("\\.csv\\'" . csv-mode)
  :init (add-hook 'csv-mode-hook (lambda () (font-lock-mode -1)))
  :ensure t)
```

Comment: After disabling `font-lock-mode`, `company-mode`, and a couple other minor modes, speed improved considerably!  I consider this a major success.

Comment: I would even consider wrapping this to only apply to large files: `(when (> (point-max) some-large-number) (font-lock-mode -1))`